# Difference of sequence from single column

Tags: sql, oracle

table data looks like

```
File Name , Sequence
f1,1  
f2,2  
f3,4  
f4,5  
f6,6  
f7,8  
f9,9
```

I want output like

```
f2,2,f3,4  
f6,6,f7,8  
f9,9
```

Idea is if sequence number difference is not 1 then previous file name and seq and current file name and sequence I want to print.

Comment: The term 'sequence' in Oracle refers to a number generator. For this scenario you may want to try different search terms.

Comment: also your wanted output conflicts with the description: `f4,5` meet the condition but you have not brought `f3,4,f4,5`

Comment: no need to have difference based on file name, it does not have any sequence significance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`lag` and/or `lead` analytical functions](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions.php) can help you with this. They allow you to select the previous or next value respectively. In an outer query you can select only those rows where the difference is not 1.

```
select
  *
from
    (select
      t.Name,
      t.Sequence,
      lead(t.Sequence) over (order by Sequence) as NextSequence
    from
      YourTable t) x
where
  x.Sequence + 1 < x.NextSequence
```